# How do I copy files in the same directory with a number changed of filename

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to copy mutiple files using patterns for a new file name.

For example:

```
./happycat1_sm.png
./happydog1.png
./happyrat1.png
```

How do I copy these files into the following filename automatically using bash-script?

```
./happycat2_sm.png
./happydog2.png
./happyrat2.png
```

Many thanks

Comment: So all your filenames start with `happy`, and there is a number before the first underscore or period?

Comment: @oguzismail yes, they are

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for file in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f); do cp "${file}" $(echo "${file}" | sed 's/1/2/'); done
```

This copies all files in the current directory, replacing 1 with 2. It's not really useful as it serve a very specific purpose and is not very reusable, but maybe it's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The below will copy files and rename the files in destination directory by replacing '1' with '2'

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in src/*
do
    cp "$file" dest/
    mv -- "dest/$file" "dest/${file/1/2}"
done
```